# What is the way to change a property for several items at the same time with different values for one property, such as color, for example

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in Filter and I am typing these words with Google translator, my English is not good, please help and thank you very much.
Description of the problem
I have four clickable containers. I would like when the user clicks on them, only the background color of the current container will be changed to red, and the rest of the three containers will have their background color changed to blue.

I tried several times and for five days I couldn't do anything unfortunately..
Where I used a variable to set the col value to be white as an initial value
This is the problem part

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
     setState(() {
      (col == Colors. white) ?col = Colors. red:col = Colors. blue;
          });
   },
   child: Container(
     alignment: Alignment. topLeft,
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: color,
     ),
     child: Text(
       'S',
     ),
   ),
),`
```

I just want when clicking on the container, it changes color with a characteristic that differs from other containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution by using a **list view** I have 5 containers when clicking on the container widget will update the current Index and change color

```
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;  // to save user click index 
  bool firstClick = false; // checking flag when first build and keep item color white 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      this.currentIndex = index;
                      this.firstClick = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: firstClick
                      ? currentIndex == index
                          ? Container(
                              // A fixed-height child.
                              color: const Color(0xffeeee00), // Yellow
                              height: 100.0,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text("Content ${index}"),
                            )
                          : Container(
                              // A fixed-height child.
                              color: Colors.lightBlue, // Yellow
                              height: 100.0,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text('Content ${index}'),
                            )
                      : Container(
                          // A fixed-height child.
                          color: Colors.white, // Yellow
                          height: 100.0,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text("Content ${index}"),
                        ));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Have Nice Day :)

Comment: Sorry... my dear brother, I didn't notice the last post, it worked...
Thank you again, please accept my apologies....have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign color with ternary operator like

```
(col == Colors.white) ? col = Colors.red:col : col = Colors.blue;
```

Or

```
col =  col == Colors.white? Colors.red:col : Colors.blue;
```

But if you are using single variable for all three container, it will change them all. Try using List instead.

```dart
class CContainerChanged extends StatefulWidget {
  const CContainerChanged({super.key});

  @override
  State<CContainerChanged> createState() => _CContainerChangedState();
}

class _CContainerChangedState extends State<CContainerChanged> {
  List<Color> containerColors = [
    Colors.cyanAccent,
    Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < containerColors.length; i++)
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: containerColors[i],
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    containerColors[i] = Colors.red;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Change color'),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

If it is about selecting single container, it will

```dart
class CContainerChanged extends StatefulWidget {
  const CContainerChanged({super.key});

  @override
  State<CContainerChanged> createState() => _CContainerChangedState();
}

class _CContainerChangedState extends State<CContainerChanged> {
  List<Color> containerColors = [
    Colors.cyanAccent,
    Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  ];

  int? selectedIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < containerColors.length; i++)
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color:  selectedIndex == i ? Colors.red : containerColors[i],
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = i;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Change color'),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: This applies to each container separately. If you click on the number one container, for example, its color becomes red, and the second, third, and fourth containers have an amber color. When you click on the third container, its background color becomes red, and the first, second, and fourth containers have an amber color.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and appreciated effort
Unfortunately, the code did not solve my problem because it seems that I did not explain my problem well...

Comment: '''onTap:(){
           setState(() {
                   (col == Colors. blueGrey || col == Colors. amber)
                       ? col = Colors. red
                       : col = Colors. amber;
                 });
         }, '''

Comment: sorry I am not getting what exactly you are trying to get. to have only single one selected, run second snippet.